# Nested update in select

Tags: mysql

I am executing

```
SELECT id as uid, (
    UPDATE trans SET paidout=1
        WHERE user_id=uid AND SUM(amount)>0.5234
)
FROM accounts
```

But no success, why doesn't this work?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That makes no sense. Please explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to first receive all `user_id` from `trans` for which the sum of `amount` is greater than 0.5234. Then use an `INNER JOIN` to match all these `user_id` values in the `UPDATE trans` statement and `SET paidout = 1`.

There's no need to involve the `accounts` table.

```
UPDATE trans
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT user_id
            FROM trans
            GROUP BY user_id
            HAVING SUM(amount) > 0.5234
    ) AS users
    ON trans.user_id = users.user_id
    SET paidout = 1;
```

DEMO @ [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0504/1)

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong syntax ,you can use select as subquery in update query, but in select query you can't do update subquery ,if you want to update  `paidout` from trans table with the scenario user_id is same as the id from accounts table and the sum of user amount  should be greater than 0.5234 you can do so

```
UPDATE trans t
JOIN accounts  ON(t.user_id = a.id)
JOIN 
(SELECT user_id FROM trans GROUP BY user_id HAVING SUM(amount) > 0.5234 ) tt
ON(tt.user_id = a.id)
GROUP BY a.id
SET t.paidout=1
```